# Erlang digraph atomicity and isolation guarantees

Tags: erlang, atomic, directed-graph, isolation

Are digraph atomicity and isolation guarantees described anywhere?

Especially:

1. What state will another process see digraph in, if another process tries to access it (vertices(), out_neighbours() etc) in the middle of del_vertex: before del_vertex, in the middle of del_vertex (i. e. vertex is deleted, edges are not or edges are deleted, vertex is not) or after del_vertex (i. e. another process will be blocked until operation is over)?
2. The same question regarding del_vertices.

If I understand right, digraph is implemented using 3 ets tables. Is there any additional locking mechanism between them in order results to be consistent?

Comment: BTW: you have two disjoint accounts one with reputation 11 and this one with reputation 6.  You should consider registering if you want to use SO from different computers.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Looking at the source of digraph.erl I can see no extra locking going on.

```
del_vertex(G, V) ->
    do_del_vertex(V, G).
```

...

```
do_del_vertex(V, G) ->
    do_del_nedges(ets:lookup(G#digraph.ntab, {in, V}), G),
    do_del_nedges(ets:lookup(G#digraph.ntab, {out, V}), G),
    ets:delete(G#digraph.vtab, V).
```

So when you look at the digraph from another process you'll see the following states depending on timing:

- Everything before the `del_vertex/2`
- Some edges to and from the vertex deleted
- The vertex itself deleted

The same happens vertex after vertex for `del_vertices/2`.

If you want more atomicity create the digraph `protected` and wrap it into its own server e.g. a `gen_server` usually implementing part of the functionality that needs close access to the digraph.